# How to install cling?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install `cling` in Ubuntu 12.04. I thought that the proper way was to download the binaries, as they are available [here](https://ecsft.cern.ch/dist/cling/current/), but the extracted folder looks like this:

```
~/Desktop/cling » ls      
bin  docs  include  lib  share
```

This requires, I think, to merge the directories content with some directories of my filesystem. I am not familiar with this method but it seems to me a bit dirty; how can I install it, upgrade it, delete it?

I was thinking about packaging it with a deb, but I never did one so I do not know if it is the correct way..

Is there a better way to install `cling`?

Comment: Yes this one http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling

Answer (score 10):

Cling now provides binary snapshots for Ubuntu (as well as Fedora and OSX) which you can find here https://root.cern.ch/download/cling

For example if you are on ubuntu 16 (or newer?):

```bsh
sudo apt install -y wget unar
wget https://root.cern/download/cling/cling_2020-11-05_ROOT-ubuntu2004.tar.bz2
unar cling_2020-11-05_ROOT-ubuntu2004.tar.bz2
./cling_2020-11-05_ROOT-ubuntu2004/bin/cling
```

Comment: Yes, but where do you place these files? There are no instructions.

Comment: @JoelCressy I think it is intended to be unpacked at the root directory ("/"). But I would be reluctant to try it, as it will be difficult to deinstall it later because the files are not under the control of the package manager.

Comment: @JoelCressy You can just run it normally from the bin directory https://github.com/root-project/cling#usage. You can add the directory to the PATH to run it from anywhere.

Comment: @Petar But where do you place these files?

Comment: @endolith, same answer as above, check the usage https://github.com/root-project/cling#usage
and add it to your user PATH (depends on which platform you are but there are many ways to do it so just check instructions for your platform)

Comment: @Petar that link doesn't say anything about where to put the files

Comment: @endolith, it shows you how to use it, where you put the files has nothing to do with cling, it's same for all binaries, without package manager you have to do this step yourself

Comment: These snapshots are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

`cling` is now packaged for GNU Guix and Guix can be installed on top of any GNU/Linux distribution such as Ubuntu.

After you've gone through the binary installation of Guix as documented here: https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Binary-Installation.html, you can install `cling` via:

```
$ guix install cling
```

And verify that it works with:

```
$ cling '#include <stdio.h>' 'printf("Hello World!\n");'
Hello World!
```

Hopefully that should save you some time compared to building Cling/LLVM from source.