# Problems installing Cling

Tags: 14.04, clang

I have been following the question: [How to install cling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406606/how-to-install-cling), which is targeted at Ubuntu 12.04. I am running 14.04 and I am not sure if that is the source of my problem.

I followed all the steps and everything worked properly until:

```
../llvm/configure --enable-targets=host
```

which outputted:

```
checking for clang... clang
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for clang++... clang++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking whether clang works... no
configure: error: Selected compiler could not find or parse C++ standard library headers.  Rerun with CC=c-compiler CXX=c++-compiler ./configure ...
```

I have `clang` installed. I tried `echo $CXX` and `echo $CC` to see what would come up, but got no output. I guess I don't really understand how those environment variables work.

How can I install `cling`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess, but this [blog post](http://www.dahlgren.so/software/2014/01/09/Wand-Of-Rust/) says:

> For some reason, the configure script didn't know to look in `/usr/bin` for `g++`. Go figure.
>
> Anyway, to fix this problem, just explicitly set the C++ compiler:
>
> ```
> $ CXX=/usr/bin/g++ ../llvm/configure
> ```

---

This is very surprising if it works, since the `configure` script does report the detection of a GNU C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

And just for completeness they now provide binary snapshots for Ubuntu (also Fedora and OSX) which you can get here https://root.cern.ch/download/cling//

Answer (score 0):

Adding to muru's answer, try this for both g++ and gcc, which are for C++ and C respectively:

```
CXX=/usr/bin/g++ CC=/usr/bin/gcc ../llvm/configure --enable-targets=host
```