# How to install cling kernel in Jupyter notebook

Tags: software-installation, kernel, c++, jupyter

From [How to install cling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406606/how-to-install-cling), I've downloaded the pre-installed binaries for cling-ubuntu on https://root.cern.ch/download/cling/

```
$ wget https://root.cern.ch/download/cling/cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16.tar.bz2
$ dtrx cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16.tar.bz2
$ cd cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16
$ ls
~/cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16/$ ls
bin include  lib  libexec  share
~/cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16/$ cd share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/
~/cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/$ ls
build        cling-cpp14  cling.ipynb           clingkernel.py  scripts
cling-cpp11  cling-cpp17  clingkernel.egg-info  __pycache__     setup.py
```

On the [documentation](https://github.com/vgvassilev/cling/tree/master/tools/Jupyter), it says:

```
pip install -e .
```

But when it comes to the step:

```
# register the kernelspec for C++17/C++14/C++11:
# the user can install whichever kernel(s) they
```

**Which C++ version should I use?** I didn't have any of those installed? I use `gcc` to compile my c++ code usually.

And even when I tried installing all with:

```
jupyter-kernelspec install cling-c++17
jupyter-kernelspec install cling-c++14
jupyter-kernelspec install cling-c++11
```

The Jupyter notebook shows the kernel but at the home page but when I create a new notebook, the kernel either dies or keeps restarting.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your steps and also ran into problems. I had better luck building from source, installing the built kernel, and running with that. I don't have details on your build; make sure you remove any previous kernels from Jupyter before trying this. To do this, based on your input above, use the following commands:

1. `~/cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel`
2. `jupyter kernelspec uninstall cling-cpp11`

Now, here are my build instructions (I'm running Ubuntu 16.04):

1. `mkdir -p ~/builds && cd ~/builds`
2. `wget https://root.cern.ch/download/cling/cling_2017-04-15_sources.tar.bz2`
3. `tar jxf cling_2017-04-15_sources.tar.bz2`
4. `mv src cling_2017-04-15`
5. `mkdir -p ~/builds/cling_2017-04-15/build`
6. `cd ~/builds/cling_2017-04-15/build`
7. `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../`
8. `make -j8`
9. `sudo make install`
10. `sudo ldconfig`
11. `cd /usr/local/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel`
12. `sud pip3 install -e .`
13. `sudo jupyer kernelspec install cling-cpp11`
14. `cd ~ && jupyter notebook`

Now, here's a simple example in Jupyter you can try. Cling is evolving, so check out the doc for the latest syntax.

[image: A simple Cling-Jupyter example.]

Answer (score 1):

There may be a discrepancy in the kernelspec directory naming between those docs and the current code.  It seems they now use "cpp" instead of "c++".  Using e.g.

```
jupyter-kernelspec install cling-cpp11
```

worked better on my cling_2017-03-30_ubuntu16 install.